# ERROR: function btrim(text[]) does not exist - BTRIM on REGEXP_MATCHES

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to trim the curly brackets from my result below by i get the error `ERROR: function btrim(text[]) does not exist`

```
select BTRIM(REGEXP_MATCHES('TType=SEND|Status=OK','Status=([^|]+)', 'g'), '{}')  as status
```

From this query  `select REGEXP_MATCHES('Status=OK','Status=([^|]+)', 'g')  as status` i get `{OK}`

However i want to trim the curly brackets and have `OK` as my final output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) `regexp_matches` returns a set (=multiple rows) of [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html). If you only expect a single match, or if you are only interested in the first one, then just pick the first element from the result.

Using `regexp_match()` is also better in that case, as it doesn't return a set, but it does not support the `'g'` modifier.

```
select (regexp_match('TType=SEND|Status=OK','Status=([^|]+)'))[1] as status
```

Comment: Assist put it in a select statement. `select (regexp_match('TType=SEND|Status=OK','Status=([^|]+)', 'g'))[1]  as status`

Comment: Now its ok after the edit . removed the 'g'